# Mapstruct: aftermapping with parameters

Tags: mapstruct

Here my code:

```
@Mapping(target = "auditoriaMetas", qualifiedByName = "sdf")
public abstract Auditoria mapToModificacio(QdCF qdcf, QdCFPresenter qdcfPresenter, Integer idInstrument);

@Named("sdf")
public List<AuditoriaMeta> mapToMetas(QdCF current, @Context QdCFPresenter incoming) {
    return null;
}
```

I want that after `mapToModificatio` is performed, `mapToMetas` is also executed.

Above code doesn't perform.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapstruct will not consider putting a normal value into one that is annotated with `@Context`. Therefor if you mark something with `@Context`, then it should be marked like that through the entire chain of calls.

For example:

```
@Mapping(target = "auditoriaMetas", source=".", qualifiedByName = "sdf")
public abstract Auditoria mapToModificacio(QdCF qdcf, @Context QdCFPresenter qdcfPresenter, Integer idInstrument);

@Named("sdf")
public List<AuditoriaMeta> mapToMetas(QdCF current, @Context QdCFPresenter incoming) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an issue now: It's telling me that `qdcf` has no property `auditoriaMetas`... that's right, but `target.auditoriaMetas = this.mapToMetas(...`. It has to avoid to find out any property named `auditoriaMetas` on `qdcf`.... Any ideas?

Comment: add `source = "."` to the `@Mapping`. (updating example)
Edit: might be `source="qdcf"` is needed instead, but I think the first one should work.